# uninstalling flash plugin completely

Tags: 10.10, flash

i've made the mistake of installing firefox flash plugin, which is horribly buggy, unstable and leaky. I need to banish this piece of rubbish out of my precious ubuntu workstation. I tried this by doing

```
sudo apt-get remove flashplugin-installer
```

but that just removes the installer, not the library

what package do i need to remove to completely uninstall this?

Comment: try going to tools>add-ons and disable the shockwave flash plugin

Comment: amusingly enough, there is none, there is just "Ubuntu firefox modifications 0.9rc2"

Comment: that's because you are in the add-ons section, it is in the plugins section

Comment: sorry, still, it shows nothing on the 'plugins in use'

Answer (score 9, accepted):

I just looked in the pre processing scripts of `flashplugin-installer`, and it appears to remove the libraries correctly. If`flashplugin-installer` is still installed you can look in `/var/lib/dpkg/info/flashplugin-installer.prerm`. to confirm it.

Otherwise, you can run the commands manually:

```
VARIANTS="iceape iceweasel mozilla firefox xulrunner midbrowser xulrunner-addons"
sudo update-rc.d -f flashplugin-installer remove >/dev/null 2>&1
sudo rm -rf /usr/lib/flashplugin-installer-unpackdir
sudo rm -rf /usr/lib/flashplugin-installer/*
sudo rm -f /var/lib/flashplugin-installer/*
sudo rm -rf /var/cache/flashplugin-installer-unpackdir
sudo rm -rf /var/cache/flashplugin-installer
sudo rm -f /usr/share/ubufox/plugins/libflashplayer.so
sudo rm -f /usr/share/ubufox/plugins/npwrapper.libflashplayer.so
for p in $VARIANTS; do
sudo update-alternatives --quiet --remove "$p-flashplugin" /usr/lib/flashplugin-installer/libflashplayer.so;
done
for p in $VARIANTS; do
sudo update-alternatives --quiet --remove "$p-flashplugin" /var/lib/flashplugin-installer/npwrapper.libflashplayer.so;
done
```

Comment: +1 thanks for the pointer. As of the date of this comment, the mechanism in `.../flashplugin-installer.prerm` has changed much from your pasted version, but has the same effect.